# How would I get a Unix command prompt in Windows / USB key?

Tags: python, ruby, unix, portable-applications

So I'm a teacher at a school, and I don't have the ability to install very many things. We currently use Windows 7. I can't change any environment variables.

I have installed the following software:

- Ruby 2.2.4 with Command Line Prompt
- Python, including IDLE

Is there any way to have a portable version? I can put them onto USB sticks.

I only want to run the most basic unix commands:
Like getting the word count of a file:

`wc file.txt`

Or displaying the contents of a file:

`file file.txt`

Literally, very basic commands like that. It's part of an exercise for my students.

Comment: Do you want linux's bash commands and programs? The only advice I can give you then is installing [ubuntu onto USB](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Comment: I don't need any of that. I simply want to run those lines of code from above in a unix command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Find a portable Cygwin(https://github.com/GathSystems/CygwinPortable for example). I've used it exactly like you - from usb stick.

Comment: I installed it, and it states:
You have set CygwinPortable to set Explorer Context menu.

Your path has changed or the Registry Keys are not set

Click OK to set registry keys with administrator access or disable 'Set Config Menu' in options

Answer (score 0):

[Busybox on windows](https://frippery.org/busybox/) should work just fine for what you want to do.

You don't need to install anything. Just downloading the stand-alone [executable](https://frippery.org/files/busybox/busybox.exe) should be enough.

Executing `busybox.exe bash` would bring you a shell which knows `wc`, `file` and `cat` among many other commands.

Comment: How do I "install" or use this program? Thanks so much!